# WPF DependencyProperty Usage

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, properties

I'm having difficulty getting Dependency Properties to work without causing compilation errors.

I have a usercontrol called TitleBar which contains this DependencyProperty:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(TitleBar), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

And on my view, in xaml:

```
<Components:TitleBar x:Name="customTitleBar" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
```

Which causes a designer/compilation error:

```
Cannot create an instance of "TitleBar". ... The invocation of the constructor on type 'TitleBar' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception. System.Exception {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException}
```

The usercontrol works perfectly without the DP on it. What am I doing wrong?

Strange thing is, when I actually put the Title="..." property into the xaml, it works in the designer until I try to compile it. From that point on, it gives me the mentioned error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DependencyProperty` is a `string` yet in `PropertyMetadata` you specify default value as false

Comment: I'd really appreciate it if you could answer a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057177/wpf-dependancy-control-updates

Answer (score 2):

You have specified the default value as `bool` when the property type is `string`.

Change

```
new PropertyMetadata(false)
```

to

```
new PropertyMetadata(null)
```