# WPF Dependency Control Updates

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, properties

I have a user control called `TitleBar` which contains this `DependencyProperty`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(TitleBar), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

The xaml for the user control looks like:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Title, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

And my xaml of the View looks like:

```
<Components:TitleBar x:Name="customTitleBar" Title="Test" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
```

When I set Title="Test" on the View that holds the TitleBar usercontrol, the changes do not show up in the designer, nor at runtime. How can I fix this?

Comment: You don't need to call `NotifyPropertyChanged("Title")`

Comment: That was a remnant from something I was trying. Removing it doesn't solve my problem of the binding not working.

Comment: Why do you have two way binding on a Label Content?

Comment: Copy+pasted binding from a former textbox. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out -- I was incorrectly handling the OnPropertyChanged event due to being confused about the parameters.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(TitleBar), new PropertyMetadata(null
    () => { (sender, e) ... }))
```

Worked after casting the parameters and calling view updates directly on them.

Comment: U also could set 'ElementName=This'('This' is the name of the usercontrol)in your binding statement because your binding source should be the UserControl not its DataContext.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have full code but my guess is that the problem is in binding context for `Label`, which by default will be `DataContext` and not `UserControl`.

```
<Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=Title}"
```

Changing binding source to be your `UserControl` should help and you shouldn't have to handle property updates from callback